# WordPress Plugin can't do echo

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, alipay

We are developing our own woocommerce payment gateway plugin (for Alipay).
After user presses "Proceed to Alipay" on the checkout page, the Alipay API takes the order information (amount, name, address, order number, etc.), creates a form with them, and them automatically submit it to the Alipay gateway.
This is how it looks like:

```
'<form id=\'alipaysubmit\' name=\'alipaysubmit\' action=\'https://openapi.alipaydev.com/gateway.do?charset=UTF-8\' method=\'POST\'><input type=\'hidden\' name=\'biz_content\' value=\'{"product_code":"FAST_INSTANT_TRADE_PAY","body":"","subject":"Wendy Wang","total_amount":"21.50","out_trade_no":"1724"}\'/><input type=\'hidden\' name=\'app_id\' value=\'2016090900467784\'/><input type=\'hidden\' name=\'version\' value=\'1.0\'/><input type=\'hidden\' name=\'format\' value=\'json\'/><input type=\'hidden\' name=\'sign_type\' value=\'RSA\'/><input type=\'hidden\' name=\'method\' value=\'alipay.trade.page.pay\'/><input type=\'hidden\' name=\'timestamp\' value=\'2017-11-13 04:50:57\'/><input type=\'hidden\' name=\'alipay_sdk\' value=\'alipay-sdk-php-20161101\'/><input type=\'hidden\' name=\'notify_url\' value=\'https://sv.icubeinfo.com/wp-content/plugins/onepigeon-alipay/notify_url.php\'/><input type=\'hidden\' name=\'return_url\' value=\'https://sv.icubeinfo.com/wp-content/plugins/onepigeon-alipay/return_url.php\'/><input type=\'hidden\' name=\'charset\' value=\'UTF-8\'/><input type=\'hidden\' name=\'sign\' value=\'ahegEWInBM8h9Gav6oNOirp881D7j8/x1gjpgSdXfgzHA81vOrDQQOdJqO2rMMj9bmm7/etVQI6MSFY1kPN9KDbPhvPeAIeygHTcDksz0k2PyNhm1P35zgctT20fWptskhZwz1vAjGVTcWOqsG7V4O9pkvnYsKm4cY83yEbFZN3G5hQHj4ZCKD/ixJFDLTtu65DonIwGV9o6qI26YCjMzUSOHVIfVFx/531R1SlGcaqhpzUzaFkMGFFLcI/F349bExDEVuXM1earg9EKZyCq/m8ZihiutPiMQkbGJnYks/casUAyA3l3m1iuWg2DqvA5tT/6psWOiIPiZSEViioMMA==\'/><input type=\'submit\' value=\'ok\' style=\'display:none;\'\'></form><script>document.forms[\'alipaysubmit\'].submit();</script>'
```

So this is what returns from Alipay API and it was stored as a string `$result`.
To run it we simply do `echo $result;`

This was all good when we test-ran it on our own laptop (XAMPP hosted): the page redirected to Alipay's page and users could choose to either pay with QR code or login to pay (I assumed the redirection took place because of the `echo`); and later when user got the payment done, it would redirect back to woocommerce's payment completion page.

However, when we tried to deploy the same codes to our server (IIS hosted), it just didn't work.

We tried using logs to trace code execution behaviors; all the codes before and after the `echo` command got logged, that means the `echo` should have been executed, but we don't understand why it didn't take effect. No redirection happened, so the woocommerce `process_checkout()` function would continue running until it hit `send_ajax_failure_response()` function, and then resulted in the error message "Error processing checkout. Please try again."

Anyone has an idea on what the problem is here?

BTW, `echo` failed even in the simple case of `echo '1234';` command.

Also, when we tried to `echo` a simple string at the loading of checkout page, it worked good. The string will be printed on the page; but not after pressing the "Proceed to Alipay" button.

"Proceed to Alipay" seems to be implemented with AJAX; is this the reason that `echo` failed? If it is, why it worked at my laptop but not on our server? How can I make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this the path on your site which AliPay redirects to? https://sv.icubeinfo.com/wp-content/plugins/onepigeon-alipay/return_url.php

Comment: Once the payment is correctly done on Alipay, that's where it goes to. In that case, users will see message like trade success.